# Wordpress Environment Management for Plugins

Tags: wordpress, workflow

I have a general question in regards to issues that could arise from a development workflow with wordpress.

I have a WordPress site with a local > staging > live environments.

First, I will say my live data can not be changed. So code is moving forward and data is moving backwards.

My question is if I run updates on the local environment and then push them to the next staging environment can this cause any problems with required database updates(only code is pushed)? I'm not familiar with how plugins record their database updates. Is it possible pushing the updated plugin to the next environment will miss it's required database updates? Or are the database updates marked in the database so WordPress will always know if the plugins database is out dated?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move only code to dev to live or local to dev. The database fields will not miss because when you update the plugin and WP core the code only update in your server not database. So you can move your code to dev or live and run WP once, the all updated functionalities run and update your database fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that only my code will be migrated. The specifics of my question is about how some CMSs like drupal can run database updates when the plugin is updated. I just want to be sure the migrated plugin will not think it has updated the database on the local environment and then misses a function call for updating the database after migrated.

Comment: Yes its sure, All updates work like drupal. Because the update version also store in DB not in any files.